# The following assertion was thrown running a test: pumpAndSettle timed out

Tags: flutter, bloc, widget-test-flutter

here is a test case which test if i failded to add data to my database it will show
error message in snackbar but my test showing pumpAndSettle timed out error

```
testWidgets(
    'renders error snack bar '
    'when status changes to failure', (tester) async {
  whenListen<TodosOverviewState>(
      todosOverviewBloc,
      Stream.fromIterable([
        const TodosOverviewState(),
        const TodosOverviewState(status: TodosOverviewStatus.failure)
      ]));

  await tester.pumpApp(buildSubject(), todosRepository: todosRepository);

  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  expect(find.byType(SnackBar), findsOneWidget);

  expect(
      find.descendant(
          of: find.byType(SnackBar),
          matching: find.text('todo status failed')),
      findsOneWidget);
});
```

Error:

Comment: Could it be that you're showing a spinner or a similiar endless progress indicator for the empty database? Because something like this is a very common problem for pumpAndSettle as it pumps new frames until the frame does not change anymore, which never happens if there is a constantly changing spinner…

Answer (score 0):

remove await tester.pumpAndSettle();
and put await tester.pump();